# Minimize downtime of the hive table with Spark saveAsTable +overwrite mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use pyspark dataframewriter's saveAsTable with overwrite mode for hive full table refresh use cases. I would like to minimize the downtime of the table availability to my impala users, its ok for my impala users to query older data until the spark load job completes.

From what I see from my test results with spark 2.4.0, the table becomes unavailable to users and gets truncated as soon as the spark job starts, regardless of the table type being external or managed.

Any out of box solutions from Spark/Hive to address this availability issue?

Comment: Missed to mention that I was using parquet table before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no out of the box solution.

1. You need to not overwrite but append, write versions and allow views to query the highest version via a view via a control table. Later you clean up older versions if acid tables.
2. Or use two tables and use a view to switch between both. More common.

Comment: Would you need a view for each table?

Comment: Yes that is correct. @neves

Answer (score 0):

It is more to do with the table format than Hive/Spark/Impala, you can look at file format that supports transactions since Parquet does not support transactions out of the box. That's one of the main benefits that the newer data lake table formats like Delta table/Hudi etc bring it to the table maintaining transaction commit logs alongside parquet data.

Both Spark/Impala seem to support Hudi which could be a possible solution.